# Azure WebJob Application insights with multiple webjobs on same server

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I wanted to get application insights in our webjobs, I have used this nuget package:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration

When we run say 2 web jobs on the same azure server (web app) we don't see a separation of the webjobs, so we don't know which web job is taking resources?
Is there something else that I can do? or need to know in order to see them separately in the insights?

[image]

Many thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something else that I can do? or need to know in order to see them separately in the insights?

AFAIK, you could not separate the resource costing for your 2 web jobs when using the application insights. Based on your requirement, I assumed that you could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and get the full memory dump based on the Process ID of your webjobs. For more details, you could follow [How to get a full memory dump in Azure App Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/).

Also, you could leverage the Crash Diagnoser extension to monitor the CPU and Memory. For more details you could refer to [How to capture and analyze a dump file when intermittent High CPU happens on Azure Web App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/01/20/how-to-capture-dump-when-intermittent-high-cpu-happens-on-azure-web-app/).

Comment: Thanks this looks like a good place for us to start, if it provided good results ill mark as answered,

Comment: We will most probably put the web jobs on separate instance so that we can track them better. a few flaws with web job it would seem, thanks for the info.